# Checkeach array item has a value

Tags: php, foreach, validation, loops

I am trying to error check a form that on submitting creates an array, however no value in that error can be empty, how can I check this using PHP, the array looks like this,

```
Array
(
    [campaign_title] => 
    [campaign_keyword] => 
    [introduction] => 
    [position] => left
    [campaign_headline] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [article] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [save_multiple] => Save
)
```

I know I would need to do something like below but from then I am totally lost,

```
foreach($post as $k=>$v) {
    //do some loop to check each key as a value?
}
```

Comment: do the subarrays need to be validated too?

Comment: yep, i think this is the bit I am struggling with most

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function will check all values in the array, regardless of depth. It will return TRUE when it finds an [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) value. Otherwise it will return FALSE.

```
function hasEmptyValues(array $array)
{
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)) as $v) {
            if(empty($v)) return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($post as $k=>$v) {
    if(is_array($v)) {
        foreach($v as $k1=>$v1) {
            if(empty($v1))
            throw new Exception($k1.' inside '.$k.' is empty');
        }
    }
    if(empty($v))
        throw new Exception($k.' is empty');
}
```

Comment: It would be better turning that into a recursive function so if the tree goes more than 2 steps deeper, it will still work.

Comment: That would be quite true for to make a more generalized solution. In fact, there are a number of other better ways to do it, but sea_1987 asked how to check the array above, and using a foreach(key/value) loop.
It seemed pertinent to keep it quick, dirty, and simple. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. Works for multidimensional arrays too and will throw an [Exception](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) when it finds an [`empty`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) value:

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function($val, $key) {
    if (empty($val)) {
        throw new Exception(htmlspecialchars($key).' is empty');
    }
});
```

Requires PHP5.3 due to the [Lambda callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want, that no Value can be empty?

Then here:

```
<?php
function checkArrayIsEmpty( $array )
{
    foreach( $array as $k => $v )
    {
        if( is_array( $v ) )
        {
            checkArrayIsEmpty( $v );
        }
        elseif( !is_array( $v ) && empty( trim( $v ) ) )
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
?>
```

use this like:

```
<?php
if( checkArrayIsEmpty( $post ) )
{
    echo 'Error!';
}
else
{
    echo '...'; // Its not empty
}
?>
```

Comment: this will check the values on first level of depth, not those of the subarrays

Comment: my fault, but now it should work, and not only subarray, subsubarray, subsubsubarray and more are now available ;) Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
function check_array($array)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            check_array($value);
        }
        if(!isset($value))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

usage: `check_array($_POST);`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a little bit unorthodox solution

First serialize the array

```
$serialized_array = serialize($your_array);
```

It will turn out like this

```
a:6:{s:14:"campaign_title";s:0:"";s:16:"campaign_keyword";s:0:"";s:12:"introduction";s:0:"";s:8:"position";a:1:{i:0;s:0:"";}s:7:"article";a:1:{i:0;s:0:"";}s:13:"save_multiple";s:4:"Save";}
```

You can count empty values by counting **""**.

```
$number_of_empty_values = substr_count($serialized_array, '""');
```